# Trying to understand MNIST and implement Train/Test model for my own dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, neural-network

I am trying to get started using Tensorflow. I have gone through the code in the example on [github](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/multilayer_perceptron.py) and wanted to implement a similar model on my data set. But when i try to implement my cost values are constant or sometimes increasing after some iterations.

```
Epoch: 0001 cost= 81.088131315
Optimization Finished!
Epoch: 0002 cost= 89.894915241
Optimization Finished!
Epoch: 0003 cost= 90.421077037
Optimization Finished!
Epoch: 0004 cost= 86.001052850
Optimization Finished!
Epoch: 0005 cost= 85.962205744
Optimization Finished!
Epoch: 0006 cost= 85.989749879
Optimization Finished!
Epoch: 0007 cost= 86.016270608
Optimization Finished!
Epoch: 0008 cost= 86.024440336
Optimization Finished!
Epoch: 0009 cost= 86.041334784
Optimization Finished!
[array([[ 13.9839468 ,  15.44447517]], dtype=float32)]
Accuracy: 1.0
```

I have 4 columns in which the first two columns are inputs and the next two columns are outputs.I am trying to build a tensor flow model which can predict the values of the output. Can someone please let me know where i am doing wrong by checking my code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("/Users/sriteja/Desktop/Al.csv")
train_X = np.array(df[df.columns[0:2]])
train_Y = np.array(df[df.columns[2:]])

# Normalizing
train_X = train_X / train_X.max(axis=0)
train_Y = train_Y / train_Y.max(axis=0)

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.001
training_epochs = 25
batch_size = 100
display_step = 1

# Network Parameters
n_hidden_1 = 7 # 1st layer number of features
n_hidden_2 = 2 # 2nd layer number of features
n_input = 2 # train_X containing shape (1000,2)
n_classes = 2 # train_Y containing shape (1000,2)

# tf Graph input
X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input])
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes])


# Create model
def multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases):
    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
    layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)
    # Output layer with linear activation
    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return out_layer

# Store layers weight & bias
weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1])),
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, n_classes]))
}
biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}

# Construct model
pred = multilayer_perceptron(X, weights, biases)

# Define loss and optimizer
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, labels=Y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

pos = 0
idx = np.arange(train_X.shape[0])

#print(idx)


# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.
        total_batch = int(1000 / batch_size)
        for i in range(1001):
            #print(pos)
            batch_x, batch_y = train_X[idx[range(pos,900)],:], train_Y[idx[range(pos,900)],:]
            pos = pos + i
            # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={X: train_X,
                                                          Y: train_Y})
            # Compute average loss
            avg_cost += c / total_batch
            # Display logs per epoch step
        if epoch % display_step == 0:
            print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch + 1), "cost=", \
                  "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))

        print("Optimization Finished!")


    # Test model
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(Y, 1))
    best = sess.run([pred], feed_dict={X: np.array([[1,1]]), Y: np.array([[1,1]])})
    #print(correct_prediction)
    print(best)

    # Calculate accuracy
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
    print("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({X: np.array([[254,276]]), Y: np.array([[254,1232]])}))
```

I dont know why my cost value either keeps increasing or stays constant for different hidden values, Can anyone please help me figure out what i am doing wrong or how to choose hidden values for this case.

Comment: Are you sure you have `n_classes = 2`? This should be your number of possible classes (in MNIST is 10, the Digits from 0 to 9). My question is why you need two columns for the outputs? Is not one enough? You need to have labels that you want to predict... Can you elaborate more on this point?